# How to configure systemd-resolved's mDNS responder to respond to multiple hostnames?

Tags: systemd, mdns

Is there a way to configure `systemd-resolved`'s mDNS-responder behavior so that my Linux box will respond to more than one mDNS hostname?

For example, I'd like to be able to ping my linux box (from within the same LAN) using `ping foo.local`, `ping bar.local`, and `ping baz.local`, and have all three of those commands get pongs back from that same computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `avahi-publish` to register an additional mDNS/DNS-SD service or host name or address mapping to your current machine.

See the serverfault answer here for configuring it as a service: https://serverfault.com/a/986437/411612